# When is the __unaligned specifier used with pointers?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, visual-c++, memory-alignment

#### Background

I'm currently working with variable length arrays with their length stored in the first two bytes of the element. Since the arrays are not padded, individual elements may be unaligned. Only the first element is guaranteed to be aligned, and the whole thing is double null terminated. These arrays are used by an API that I need access to and cannot alter.

I'm writing a `const_iterator` that takes an aligned pointer and can iterate over the unaligned elements. The API for these arrays specifies '__unaligned' for pointers to elements, so I'm mostly trying to confirm or deny my understanding of applying the `__unaligned` specifier.

#### The Question

Simply: when should the `__unaligned` specifier be used when dealing with pointers to potentially unaligned data?

Let us say that I have

```
Foo *foo = pointerToFirstElement(); //aligned
auto next_ptr = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(foo);
next_ptr += bytesToNextElement(foo);
//reinterpret_cast here to retrieve the next element
```

Do I then need to check if the new address is aligned, and if not, `reinterpret_cast<Foo __unaligned *>(next_ptr)` to access the next element?

Further, can I use `__unaligned` as part of template argument deduction in a manner similar to `const`, like so?

```
template <class T, class = std::enable_if<std::is_pointer<T>::value>>
struct is_pointer_to_aligned_data : std::true_type {};

template <class T>
struct is_pointer_to_aligned_data<T __unaligned *> : std::false_type {};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Simply: when should the __unaligned specifier be used when dealing with pointers to potentially unaligned data?

- In short, when the platform you are using demands it, e.g. the Windows API on x86-64. It's a legacy throwback to Itanium and not a concern on x86-32. Some other processors also have issues with unaligned data (e.g. MIPS).
- Specifically, the `__unaligned` specifier simply means data may not be on an aligned boundary. [*It has no meaning outside of a pointer type.*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa228710(v=vs.60).aspx)
- On 32 bit x86 platforms, Windows itself simply declares `#define __unaligned`.

> Do I then need to check if the new address is aligned, and if not, reinterpret_cast(next_ptr) to access the next element?

- Given the above, no. Adding the `__unaligned` specifier is useful to access functions that take arguments that are pointers to unaligned data, such as [`ILFindLastID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776440(v=vs.85).aspx).
- **Followup:** How do you remove the __unaligned specifier when unneeded? Use [`const_cast`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz6at95h.aspx) or do like Windows: `#define __unaligned` before including a header. ***Use preprocessor checks that you are on x86-64 or another platform where this is safe.***

Lastly,

> Further, can I use __unaligned as part of template argument deduction in a manner similar to const, like so?

Yes, but like this:

```
template< class T > struct is_aligned_helper : std::true_type {};
template< class T > struct is_aligned_helper<__unaligned T> : std::false_type {};
template< class T > struct is_aligned : is_aligned_helper<typename std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_pointer_t<T>>> {};
```

You need to remove the pointer first to check the type of the pointed to data. Then remove any const or volatile to get the bare type + `__unaligned` (if present).

Answer (score 0):

With Visual C++ the `__unaligned` keyword was only introduced to support Intel Itanium (`_M_IA64`) which required special handling for unaligned reads.

*Windows Server 2008 R2* and *Windows XP x64 Edition* were the last versions of Windows that supported [Itanium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itanium).

This doesn't apply to Windows on x86, x64, ARM, or ARM64.

**In short, don't use it at all in your code.**

See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/unaligned)

Comment: I have no choice: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773321(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I'm fairly sure that's a different meaning of 'unaligned'. In any case, you don't need to use the ``_unaligned`` keyword: you can just read/write unaligned data and the hardware handles it. In C/C++ on x86 and x64 architectures, you can read a single byte at any address and it just works.

Comment: `typedef /* [wire_marshal] */ ITEMIDLIST __unaligned *LPITEMIDLIST;`

Comment: As I said, that's _only_ there for Itanium. It's ignored on all other platforms. Microsoft stopped supporting Itanium some time ago, but there's still bits of it lingering about in the Platform headers. Unless you are writing for Itanium, ignore ``__unsigned`` and never use it.

Comment: Then why is `__unaligned` appearing in my compiler errors if it's ignored? Specifically, this is _after_ scrubbing all reference to `__unaligned` in my code. It's in the `typedefs`.

Comment: Please add the full text of the 'compiler errors' to your original question as that will likely tell me exactly what is happening. My answer is correct in the sense that your code should never need it.

Comment: I'm not going back through this with you four years later. You are demonstrably wrong. I'm not ignoring my eyes or the documentation because you insist that you are correct.

Comment: Right, the original thread quite old. Sorry :)   I have no doubt that there are many lingering cases of ``__unaligned`` in Windows headers even though IA64 is now fully past end-of-life (July 2021), which is why I was curious what the actual error messages from the compiler were. It *shouldn't* matter for client code, which is why I was wondering *why* it matters in your case.

Comment: Let it go. You answered your own question.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn that's actually not quite true. __unaligned does seem to change generated code if you have alignas(16) with no arch specified. For example, it will then sometimes choose movaps unless you have __unaligned in which case it will movups. Trying to use movaps with unaligned data would cause a crash.